# Maven site fails on unpack-dependencies when trying to get javadoc report

Tags: maven, reporting, javadoc, rpm

I have a multi module project with the following configuration:

- A reactor pom that defines reporting plugins
- B parent pom (child of A) that groups together several child modules
- C child module of B (standard java module)
- D child module of B (RPM packaging)

When I run mvn site on B then I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project B: failed to get report for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:unpack-dependencies (content-unpack-zips) on project D: Artifact has not been packaged yet. When used on reactor artifact, unpack should be executed after packaging: see MDEP-98. -> [Help 1]
```

[Here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-98) is the bug that is mentioned in the console output. But I found no workaround that would work in my case when studying the comments on this issue.

I already tried to skip the site plugin and/or the report generation for D but it did not work. So I would like to know if there is a workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the following solution for this problem: Our rpm modules are added only when a special profile is active (linux). So we can simply call `site -P !linux`. This causes the linux profile to be deactivated and the build runs without problems.